# Solving Class loading issue for a plugin implementation on a Server Container

Tags: jakarta-ee, plugins, jetty, classloader

I'm trying to implement my own version of a [Filter/Handler](http://openig.forgerock.org/doc/gateway-guide/index.html#chap-customizing) on OpenIG.

I create it's own maven project on eclipse, compiled the sample and packed it into a jar.

I am running OpenIG 2.1.0 on a Jetty 8.

The openig war is deployed under $JETTY_HOME/webapps, while the jar I created is under $JETTY_HOME/lib/ext.

The exception I am facing is NoClassDefFound the GenericFilter class that my filter extends. GenericFilter exists in the openig war, as an "inlined" jar

I understand that this is an issue of classloading. The Plugin Jar and OpenIG war does not share the same class loader.

My question is: what form of packaging is suitable for such scenario ?

1. I can rebuild the war with my new class - Doesn't seem logical, There should be decoupling of the war and the plugin
2. I can wrap the plugin as a war - Still doesn't make sense.
3. Using OSGI - way overkill for this, and openIG is not an OSGI bundle

any ideas ?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/forgerock/openig/filter/GenericFilter
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at org.forgerock.openig.util.JsonValueUtil.classForName(JsonValueUtil.java:80)
 at org.forgerock.openig.util.JsonValueUtil.asClass(JsonValueUtil.java:94)
 at org.forgerock.openig.heap.HeapImpl.init(HeapImpl.java:64)
 at org.forgerock.openig.federation.FederationGatewayServlet.init(FederationGatewayServlet.java:67)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:456)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:535)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:972)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:906)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:910)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:565)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.forgerock.openig.filter.GenericFilter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at org.forgerock.openig.util.JsonValueUtil.classForName(JsonValueUtil.java:80)
 at org.forgerock.openig.util.JsonValueUtil.asClass(JsonValueUtil.java:94)
 at org.forgerock.openig.heap.HeapImpl.init(HeapImpl.java:64)
 at org.forgerock.openig.federation.FederationGatewayServlet.init(FederationGatewayServlet.java:67)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:456)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:535)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:972)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:906)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:442)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:910)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:565)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)C
```

Answer (score 0):

The classes in a war are not available to the classes in the lib directory when they are loaded.  It sounds like you want to run OpenIG and include some custom parts in their WAR.  If you are using Maven, you can do this with the [Maven WAR Plugin and Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#overlays).  Overlays allow you to add code to an existing WAR to create a new war.